# Excel-Statements Logical Conception

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Good Evening!

I'm trying to make some excel statement to have the appearance below:

[image: Ticket]

What i'm trying to do is that:

```
if(A1=1 and B1=0) output would be A1=1 and B2=0
if(A1=0 and B1=1) output would be A1=0 and B2=1
if(A1=0 and B2=0) output is an error.
if(A1=1 and B2=1) output is an error.
if(A1="-"and B2="-") output would be A1="-" and B2="-".
```

Same goes for all cell of A and B.Any suggestions?

Comment: By output, do you mean a message box? Or do you want the value in the cells to be changed to the output?

Comment: Just so you know why @VBAPete is asking, a formula cannot reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need post the following code, that activates your macro when anything is changed in column A or B into the Sheet Object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Evaluatecells
    End If

End Sub
```

And the code below, that evaluates your cells for the criteria, will go in the module:

```
Sub Evaluatecells()

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For x = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = 0 And Cells(x, 2).Value = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Error - Values in A1 and B1 cannot be both 0.")
            Exit For
        ElseIf Cells(x, 1).Value = 1 And Cells(x, 2).Value = 1 Then
            MsgBox ("Error - Values in A1 and B1 cannot be both 1.")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The concept is that if user enters values 0 or 1 output would be 1 or 0 on only one cell, not both.
For - and - output would be - on both cells.
For 1 and 1 if someone types both cell 1 an alert will come up to say only 0 is accepted to that cell.
Same goes for 0.
Thank you Jim!

Comment: @Jimmy84 Did the updated code end up working for you?